# Total assets and current assets

Tags: stocks, terminology, assets, market-data, liabilities

I was looking into company investment data and was doing some ratio calculation when I stumbled upon 4 Terms `"Total Assets"`, `"Current Assets"`, `"Total Liabilities"`, `"Current Liabilities"`.  My instinct tells me that `Total Assets` should always be `>` than `Current Assets`.
 However when I went to [msn.money 10-Year-Historic data](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/financial-statements?symbol=US%3aDTE)  I have found 2 columns named `Current Assets` and `Current Liabilities` that are BIGGER when `Total Current Assets` and `Total Current Liabilities` for same year same company in [msn.money Balance-Sheet page](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/stock-balance-sheet/?symbol=US%3ADTE&stmtView=Ann). Which can only mean one thing - I don't understand what `Total Assets` and `Current Assets` actually mean.

**What is the difference between them and how can `Total Assets` be less when `Current Assets`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice these headings under "Total Non-Current Assets" (These would be the difference between Total Current Assets and Total Assets to my mind as Assets are either current or non-current):

Net Property,Plant,and Equipment

Gross Property,Plant,and Equipment

Accumulated Depreciation

Goodwill and Other Intangible Assets

Goodwill

Other Intangible Assets

Investments and Advances

Notes Receivable,Non-Current

Derivative Assets,Non-Current

The Depreciation being one that is negative that could cause the sum of "Total Assets" to be less than "Total Current Assets."

From [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/accumulated-depreciation.asp):

> Definition of 'Accumulated Depreciation'
>
> The cumulative depreciation of an asset up to a single point in its
>   life. Regardless of the method used to calculate it, the depreciation
>   of an asset during a single period is added to the previous period's
>   accumulated depreciation to get the current accumulated depreciation.
>
> An asset's carrying value on the balance sheet is the difference
>   between its purchase price and accumulated depreciation.
>
> Investopedia explains 'Accumulated Depreciation'
>
> A company buys an asset for $5,000 that has a five-year lifespan and
>   zero salvage value. The company uses straight-line depreciation, and
>   the asset depreciates at a rate of $1,000 per year.
>
> In year one, depreciation will be $1,000, as will accumulated
>   depreciation, and carrying value of the asset will be $4,000.
>
> In year two, depreciation will be $1,000, accumulated depreciation
>   will be $2,000 ($1,000 from the current year + $1,000 accumulated from
>   previous years) and carrying value will be $3,000.
>
> Each subsequent year will follow the same process.

Comment: Hello JB, Could you please expand on how Deprecation could make `total assets` be less than `current assets`. I am not trying to be a smart-ass, I am really trying to learn something. BTW Why did you picked headings on `Total Non-Current Assets`? Sorry if I sound like a moron I just recently got into investments.

Answer (score 1):

The 10-Year Summary is mislabeled.

They previously displayed the data for current assets & liabilities, but it appears as if they now show data for total assets & liabilities but haven't changed the label.